# Should a new node on the network execute all the transactions since the very first?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, contract-invocation, nodes, network

This question might be dumb, I'm sorry in advance. I only had that much time for gaining expertize.

Say there is a huge working blockchain full of smart contracts and transactions on those smart contracts.

As far as I understand, all the nodes must execute all those smart contracts and all the transactions that change state of those contracts.

Then there is a new node joining this old blockchain. In order to have a correct state of all the contracts it should download the entire blockchain and then execute all the transactions related to smart contracts?

Is this vision correct, where do I miss something? Thanks!

Comment: Yes. This is correct! Your subject is more accurate: *all* transactions (not just the smart contracts) need to be verified by executing them to get the blockchain to the correct state (i.e., a state for which there is consensus).

Comment: Thanks! So, just to confirm. Once a new node is started on the network, it first downloads the entire blockchain (30GB of data if this is a public Ethereum blockchain) and then executes each and every contract downloaded. Only after that you can focus on mining new transactions. Correct?

Comment: That's right; or you can mine to a pool (who keeps a copy of the blockchain synced) and have reduced variance. The cost is about 3-10% inefficiency (depending on your latency and some other factors) + the pool fee (1-2%?), assuming the pool has 100% uptime and is properly managed.

Comment: Do you have a source for your claims?

Comment: How long do these transactions take to execute. It seems like if you were to execute every transaction that exists on the blockchain on a fresh node, it would take a really long time to do so before the new node can start the process of adding new blocks to the blockchain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As far as I understand, all the nodes must execute all those smart
>   contracts and all the transactions that change state of those
>   contracts.

Yup that's right.

There is a slight nuance - executions on a blockchain only occur once. A full node will perform a block verification that the state of the chain is correct based on those executions - its more of a replay/simulation than a rerun. It is that verification that partly keeps the blockchain secure as more nodes verify the state and only keep the blocks that conform to the protocol rules (longest chain wins).